# Filter nested object from parent object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a parent object with a child array of objects nest underneath. Each object contains an `id` key with a unique value. A filter function needs to search the parent object for an `id`, if it does not equal the given `id` then recursively search through nested objects for the `id` until it is found. Once the object with the given key is found the remove and return the updated `myObject`.

The structure looks as followed:

```js
    let myObject = {
        key: 1,
        name: 'hello',
        children: [
            {
                key: 2,
                name: 'world',
                children: []
            },
            {
                key: 3,
                name: 'hope',
                children: [
                    {
                        key: 4,
                        name: 'you',
                        children: [{
                            key: 5,
                            name: 'are',
                            children: []
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        key: 6,
                        name: 'having',
                        children: [{
                            key: 7,
                            name: 'fun',
                            children: []
                        }]
                    }
    
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    
    
    let given = 4;

    if (myObject.key !== given) {
      myObject = searchChild(myObject, given)
    } else {
      myObject = {}
    }

    function searchChild(parent, given) {
        parent.children.map(child => {
          return child.children.filter(item => {
            if (item.key === given) return item;
            else if (item.key !== given 
                && child.children.length > 0 
                && child.children != undefined) { 
                  searchChild(child.children, given);
            }
          })
        })
      }
```

Currently, I am receiving a type error when running the recursive function.

The output should look like where the keys are updated to the new order in tree:

```
{
        key: 1,
        name: 'hello',
        children: [
            {
                key: 2,
                name: 'world',
                children: []
            },
            {
                key: 3,
                name: 'hope',
                children: [
                    {
                        key: 4,
                        name: 'having',
                        children: [{
                            key: 5,
                            name: 'fun',
                            children: []
                        }]
                    }

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: `searchChild` never returns a defined value and doesn't mutate its arguments. It should do one of those things. Which one were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You pass `child.children` but you have to pass `child` you already iterate through `children` in the function.

```js
let myObject = {
        key: 1,
        name: 'hello',
        children: [
            {
                key: 2,
                name: 'world',
                children: []
            },
            {
                key: 3,
                name: 'hope',
                children: [
                    {
                        key: 4,
                        name: 'you',
                        children: [{
                            key: 5,
                            name: 'are',
                            children: []
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        key: 6,
                        name: 'having',
                        children: [{
                            key: 7,
                            name: 'fun',
                            children: []
                        }]
                    }
    
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    
    
    let given = 4;

    if (myObject.key !== given) {
      myObject = searchChild(myObject, given)
    } else {
      myObject = {}
    }

    function searchChild(parent, given) {
        if(parent && parent.children) {
parent.children.map(child => {
          return child.children.filter(item => {
            if (item.key === given) return item;
            else if (item.key !== given 
                && child.children.length > 0 
                && child.children != undefined) { 
                  searchChild(child, given);
            }
          })
        })
      }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes! This is a great start, but only a partial answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is function you can call for your object

```
function searchInChild(parent,key){
      parent.children = parent.children.filter((c)=>{
        if(key == c.key ){
          result  = c;
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });

      if(result == null){
        for(c in parent.children){
          searchInChild(parent.children[c],key);
        }
      }

    }
```

Where, you can simply pass searchInChild(myObject,key) & make result global variable.